# MultiPointZ wkt geom "multiple part to single parts" is losing Z coordinate

Tags: qgis, multipoint

I have a "MultiPointZ" unique wkt geom feature constituted of several hundreds of points (X,Y,Z) in a shapefile.

To split all these points each in a single feature, I used the "Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to singleparts".

It works fine except that it ended up only with "Point" geom features instead of "PointZ", thus losing the Z coordinate.

Any ideas about how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

If you have some python skills, you could just fix the processing module. It should not be hard at all.

1. locate it on your harddrive
2. Replace [the whole block dealing in complicated ways with geometries](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/MultipartToSingleparts.py#L87-L103) with a simple 

   `return QGis.singleType(wkbType)`
3. Test
4. *Optional extra step: make a [processing test case for it](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/tests#algorithm-tests)*
5. Make a pull request on github so it's fixed for everyone